# Get value when :checked from input type color

Tags: javascript, html, input

I've written this code, I want to get a value with every click of the input. The first two inputs work correctly, but 3 do not. I want 3 to work on this principle: When I click on it, a window for selecting a color opens, and when I select it, I get the hex color of the selected color in the console. Please help me.
EDIT: As you can see in the fiddle. I want it to be possible to select black and white and choose a colour using the input type color. I want the input type color to get a frame like the other input items. In addition, is there anything you can do to make sure that when you select a color, the color gradient changes to the one you chose instead?

```js
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for(i=0;i<radio.length;i++){
  radio[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    var color = document.querySelector('input:checked').value;
    console.log(color);
  });
}
```

```css
input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
label {
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    margin: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
label:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000;
}
label:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
label:nth-child(6) {
    background: conic-gradient(from 90deg,violet,indigo,blue,green,yellow,orange,red,violet);
}
input:checked + label {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
                0 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color1" value="#000000" checked>
<label for="color1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color2" value="#fffffff">
<label for="color2"></label>
<input type="color" name="color" id="color3">
<label for="color3"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help to separate it and use the selector color at the final color.

if you select the radio it will set the value to `mastercolor` too

```
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var masterColor = document.getElementById('color3');
for(i=0;i<radio.length;i++){
  radio[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    var color = document.querySelector('input:checked').value;
    masterColor.value = color
  });
}

<input type="radio" name="color" id="color1" value="#000000" checked>
<label for="color1">Black</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color2" value="#fffffff">
<label for="color2">White</label>

<input type="color" name="mastercolor" value="#000000" id="color3">
<label for="color3">Pick</labe>
```

for that user mastercolor for final color

Comment: Thanks a lot! And you know what to do if I click on the input type color to remove the checked from other inputs?

Comment: I'm gonna ask another question to better illustrate what I mean :D

Comment: I recommend to use another input instead of Radio that must be click at lead one

Comment: I edited the question, I think it's now clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to grab the value of the `input` after it has changed.
Hope this small snippet helps.

[Edit]

Added Question's code snippet. With working example.
You can use a `for` loop as well, but you need to use `change` on a color picker, instead of `click` event, since it's changed after the `click` has happened.

[/Edit]

```js
function color(option) {

  let colors = document.querySelectorAll("label");
  for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    colors[i]
      .style
      .boxShadow = "";
  }

  let color;
  switch (option.type) {
  
    case "click":
      color = option.toElement.value;
      break;
    case "change":
      color = option.target.value;
      document
        .getElementById(option.target.id + "l")
        .style
        .background = color;
      document
        .getElementById(option.target.id + "l")
        .style
        .boxShadow = "inset 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0 0 1px #000";
      let checked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
      for (i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
        checked[i].checked = false;
      }
      break;
  }
  console.log(color);
}
```

```css
input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
label {
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    margin: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
label:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000;
}
label:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
label:nth-child(6) {
    background: conic-gradient(from 90deg,violet,indigo,blue,green,yellow,orange,red,violet);
}
input:checked + label {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
                0 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color1" onclick="color(event)" value="#000000" checked>
<label for="color1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color2" onclick="color(event)" value="#fffffff">
<label for="color2"></label>
<input type="color" name="color" id="color3" onchange="color(event)" value="#abcdef">
<label for="color3" id="color3l"></label>
```

Comment: OK, but I edited the question, I think it's now clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: Works pretty cool, but there is no circle around the input to choose the colors if it is checked :/

Comment: With the information I've provided, you should be able to figure that one out yourself, but since I really enjoy this small challenge, I've updated my code with unchecking and circle graphic around the color picker.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't this:

```
<input type="color" name="color" id="color3" value="#f90000">
```

be:

```
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color3" value="#f90000">
```

Comment: But I want pick color from input type color

Comment: Then this input type doesn;t have checked state. You would have to add a separate event listener for this without :checked, then it should work

Comment: I edited the question, I think it's now clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Your third input is `input type="color"` instead of `input type="radio"`. I dont think the input type 'color' has a 'checked' state. 
'color3' also has no value, so there is nothing to pick.

```
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color1" value="#000000" checked>
<label for="color1">Black</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color2" value="#fffffff">
<label for="color2">White</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color3" value="#FFC0CB" >
<label for="color3">Pink</label>
```

Comment: I edited the question, I think it's now clear what I want to achieve.